# usr/local/lib/libbz2.a: could not read symbols: Bad value

Tags: python, installation, module, bz2

While installing python, I was getting following error:

```
usr/local/lib/libbz2.a: could not read symbols: Bad value

/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libbz2.a(bzlib.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.text’ can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
```

Then have used following command to install python.

```
./configure --prefix=/home/bhanuday/Softwares/Python/installation3/  LDFLAGS='-L/home/bhanuday/Softwares/library/libffi/installation/lib64 -L/home/bhanuday/Softwares/library/bzip2/installation/lib' CFLAGS="-I/home/bhanuday/Softwares/library/bzip2/installation/include"
make
make install
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that, though Python was able to find bzip2 installation, it was not able to use it properly. So, I had to recompile the bzip2 installation with following modification in its makefile.

I went into bzip2 source directory, open the 'makefile' in a text editor and then replace the following line

```
CC=gcc
```

with

```
CC=gcc -fPIC
```

then again saved the file. Recompile the bzip2 with following commands:

```
make clean
make
make install
```

And, after that I compiled the python. And.. wawwww... not the _bz2 module is successfully installed.

Thanks to the post: http://matrafox.info/problem-with-ffmpeg-usrlocalliblibbz2-a-could-not-read-symbols-bad-value.html